# Can a 3rd-level Faerie Fire spell be seen in magical darkness from the Darkness spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, advantage-and-disadvantage

The relevant part of the description of the [*darkness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) spell reads:

> Magical darkness spreads from a point you choose within range to fill
> a 15-foot radius sphere for the duration. [...] nonmagical light can’t
> illuminate it.
>
> [...]
>
> If any of this spell’s area overlaps with an area of light created by
> a spell of 2nd level or lower, the spell that created the light is
> dispelled.

The description of the [*faerie fire*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/faerie-fire) spell reads, in part:

> Each object in a 20-foot cube within range is outlined in blue, green,
> or violet light (your choice). Any creature in the area when the spell
> is cast is also outlined in light if it fails a Dexterity saving
> throw. For the duration, objects and affected creatures shed dim light
> in a 10-foot radius.

Given this, casting [*faerie fire* using a spell slot of 3rd level or higher inside an area of magical darkness created by the *darkness* spell should work](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/61997/darkness-vs-daylight-interactions).

**What exactly would the effects be on a creature inside the *darkness* and *faerie fire* who failed their saving roll?**

Specifically who would get advantage, disadvantage, or be rolling normally (due to cancellation of advantage and disadvantage), in the case of an attacker in the darkness, another outside, and the original creature?

Comment: Related: [What happens to lasers entering an area of magical darkness?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134628/what-happens-to-lasers-entering-an-area-of-magical-darkness) and [Does Darkness cast a shadow?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55748/does-darkness-cast-a-shadow)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### It depends on where they are standing

The *darkness* spell is described in such a way as to give the impression that it is something tangible that spills out around corners, but can be blocked by objects. Think of *darkness* as not unlike a *fog cloud* spell.

> The darkness spreads around corners. [...] Completely covering the source of the darkness with an opaque object, such as a bowl or a helm, blocks the darkness.

Likewise, *darkness* engulfs non-magical light - or rather, it cannot be illuminated by non-magical light. This means that magical light **can** illuminate it.

Light in 5e is described as having bounds. *Faerie fire* indicates that afflicted creatures shed dim light, which only means that area imposes disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks; attacking into dim light behaves as normal.

This is where location comes into play. The bounds of the dim light must penetrate the bounds of the *darkness* spell in order to be seen. Put another way, there must be no darkness between you and the creature. You need to check the positions and radius of the area of *darkness* and creatures affected by the *faerie fire*.

If the radius of the *darkness* spell's area completely engulfs the radius of the dim light, they cannot be seen by you from any angle. If they are 5 feet or more away from the center of the darkness, they can be seen from the direction the dim light is from the center. This is sort of mathy, but really no more difficult than normal line of sight. Darkness spills out around corners continuously, so just visualize or draw the circles and draw a line to the center of the dim light.

[image: illustration of the visibility of an overlapping area of upcast *faerie fire* and *darkness* from various positions]

### Who do I have advantage against?

Advantage and disadvantage hinge on who can see whom. In general, you have disadvantage on attacks against targets you cannot see, and advantage on attacks against targets who can't see you. However, when neither target can see each other (such as when a target is standing in darkness and you are not), you have neither disadvantage or disadvantage.

From the [basic rules on advantage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#AdvantageandDisadvantage):

> If circumstances cause a roll to have both advantage and disadvantage, you are considered to have neither of them, and you roll one d20. This is true even if multiple circumstances impose disadvantage and only one grants advantage or vice versa.

This means that *faerie fire*'s advantage only has an effect when no disadvantage is imposed. It is important to note that, as explained in the question, *faerie fire* must be cast at a level greater than 2nd, or *darkness* will dispel it.

You have advantage against:

- Targets you can see that can't see you. It shouldn't matter the
  circumstances in which this takes place (Devil's Sight, location,
  etc); if you can determine who can see whom, this will suffice for
  advantage.
- Targets affected by *faerie fire* that you can see
- Targets in any situation in which you have at least 1 source of
  advantage and no sources of disadvantage

You have disadvantage against:

- Targets not affected by *faerie fire* that you can't see and that can
  see you
- Targets in any situation in which you have at least 1 source of
  disadvantage and no sources of advantage

You have neither advantage nor disadvantage against:

- Targets you can't see that also can't see you
- Targets affected by *faerie fire* that you can't see
- Targets standing in dim light that you have line of sight to (i.e.
  you can both see each other)
- Targets in any situation in which you have any number of sources of
  advantage **and** disadvantage (at least one of each)

This answer hinges on the fact that the *darkness* spell is dark in 3 dimensions, much like a 15-foot radius of fog or smoke. I believe this is true because of how the darkness spills around corners and can be blocked by objects.

If the *darkness* spell only "darkens" objects and ground in its radius, then it makes sense to imply that the *faerie fire* penetrates through it, making line of sight meaningless. Is it a floating black orb, or is it a radius of darkened objects? Again, I say the former, but I would personally leave this up to the DM.

Comment: Great answer! The only other thing I would like to see in it is if someone is standing in the area inside the darkness and inside both the darkness and light.

Comment: You mean someone not afflicted by Faerie fire standing in the dim light?

Comment: There are three cases not covered in your answer. someone in the darkness not inside the dim light (which I think from your answer, you'd likely argue can't see anyone), someone in the the dim light who rolled successfully, and the "target". Can the target see the people who can see them?

Comment: @J.A.Streich I've added an edge case, in case you are curious (2nd point of Advantage list)

Comment: Hm, does *faerie fire* block the darkness emanating from *darkness*? I.e. is there a “shadow” of light behind the one with *faerie fire* that is unaffected by either spell?

Comment: That new edge case is one I always intended, and knew about; but, adding to the answer I think makes the answer more complete.

Comment: @KRyan doubtful, seeing as how it spreads around corners. It is more like a sphere of smoke than it is a light source working in reverse. But you're welcome to dispute that :) There's perhaps a precedence for that type of behavior, because fireball could be argued to be able to be contained inside of a small space, as someone jumping on a grenade

Answer (score 9):

## Yes, it can be seen

In disagreement with [Premier Bromanov's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73457/can-level-3-faerie-fire-be-seen-in-magical-darkness/73465#73465):

If you're in normal darkness and someone has a torch, it illuminates things up to X feet away, but you can still see the light even if you're outside the range.

Since Darkness won't stop the Faerie Fire's light, it will illuminate things up to X feet away, but you can still see the light even if you're not in the range.

Assuming a failed save, this would let people anywhere outside the darkness be able to see someone who is illuminated inside the darkness.  However, the people inside the darkness (assuming normal/darkvision) would not be able to see the people outside the spell, since the normal light illuminating those people would not penetrate the darkness.

Comment: I just realized that darkness is blocked by **Opaque** objects, and was curious if a  glass object would block darkness. Maybe that might be a good point to hit on

Comment: @PremierBromanov Glass objects aren't opaque, so not sure what you're wondering.

Comment: Well I think it pokes holes in my answer as behaving exactly like fog. I thought it behaving more like light might bolster your answer.

Comment: @PremierBromanov Ah, I see what you're saying.