# Can Truesight (as from the True Seeing spell) see through the Hunger of Hadar or Darkness spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can [Truesight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/monsters#Senses) (as granted by the [*true seeing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-seeing) spell) see through the darkness of the [*hunger of Hadar*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hunger-of-hadar) or [*darkness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) spells? For *hunger of Hadar*, would vision be obscured by "milky, otherworldly tentacles"?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Can level 3 Faerie Fire be seen in Magical Darkness?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73457/can-level-3-faerie-fire-be-seen-in-magical-darkness/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes for the *Darkness* spell, no for *Hunger of Hadar*.

As is stated in the PHB, pg. 185, truesight can definitely allow vision in darkness, both normal and magical, much as the Devil's Sight for Warlocks. Given that the description of the *Darkness* spell notes that it creates a magical darkness, creatures with truesight can see in and through it.

*Hunger of Hadar* is another beast altogether. It effectively creates a void that warps the fabric of space, and blinds creatures within the area. If a character is within the spell, then truesight does nothing as it doesn't protect from the *blinded* condition, which this spell applies. As for any creature with truesight trying to look in or through the sphere, this also is impossible, as the spell doesn't mask reality so much as create a gate to another plane that isn't superimposed with the material plane, as the ethereal plane is. This is also why no light spell, regardless of the level, can illuminate the darkness created by this spell. Basically, the darkness present isn't created by a spell, but as a side effect of the appearance of that dimensional gate.

Answer (score 18):

## The *Darkness* spell, yes. *Hunger of Hadar*, no.

The description of truesight on PHB p. 185, says:

> A creature with truesight can, out to a specific range, see in normal and magical darkness...

*Darkness* is specifically stated to create magical darkness so yes, a creature with truesight would be able to see in *darkness*.

*Hunger of Hadar*, however, says:

> A 20-foot-radius sphere of blackness and bitter cold appears [...] *The void* creates a warp in the fabric of space...

*Hunger of Hadar* doesn't create darkness (in the sense of game mechanics), magical or otherwise; it just creates a black void of space, so a creature with truesight wouldn't be able to see within that space.

As further backup, Jeremy Crawford - lead rules designer - has stated that an ability that's almost identically worded to the above quoted text for truesight [isn't meant to see into the void of *Hunger of Hadar*](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/704828756616044544):

> *Devil's Sight* is meant to pierce the dark created by a spell like darkness, not the void of hunger of Hadar.

Comment: I was aware of the Devils Sight case, but felt that a sixth level temporary spell might be able to defeat a third level spell where an always on ability you can pick at second level could not. "See things as they actually are" and "See into the ethereal plane." being relevant here as the Hunger of Hadar creates a bubble of, in essence, another plane.

Comment: @Billythebabygoat. Since you're specifically asking about the True Seeing spell, I've edited a mention of that into the question.

Answer (score -4):

How can you be have true sight and be blind?
What is darkness but the absence of light?

If i were the DM and someone had true sight then i would say they could still see in the void.  Although in this case there is nothing to see but the otherworldly tentacles rubbing against you and whoever else might be in there with you.
They would also be able to see where the voided ending to help guide them out.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! You should take the [tour] if you haven't already. Can you point to any citations of the game rules or official rulings to back up your suggested ruling?