# Eldritch Devil Sight and Darkness spell

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, vision-and-light, eldritch-invocations

Situation:
Drow Warlock casts darkness. Moves out of the effect area then uses devil sight to see through the darkness to use ranged combat against enemies.

1. Devil Sight description states "You can see normally in darkness, both magical and nonmagical, to a distance of 120ft."
2. Key word is 'in'.
3. No where does it say into or through.

Q: Can the Drow Warlock see through the magical darkness and engage the enemy with ranged combat?

Comment: Related: "[How does the warlock's Devil's Sight invocation work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/91100)" and "[Does the Darkness spell block vision?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86510)" and "[Does the Darkness spell cast a shadow?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55748)" and "[Can Truesight see through the Hunger of Hadar or Darkness spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99967)" and "[Can level 3 Faerie Fire be seen in Magical Darkness?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/73457)" and "[Does Devil's Sight enable one to see into Hunger of Hadar?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59960)"

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Yes, you can see normally in or through the *darkness* spell.

Devil's Sight says:

> You can see normally in darkness, both magical and nonmagical, to a distance of 120 feet.

You have pointed out some confusion with the placement of the word "in" here. "In" is a preposition that connects "darkness" with something else in the sentence. In this case, it is connecting the predicate phrase "can see" with "darkness". We have "can see in darkness". Notably, *the prepositional phrase "in darkness" is not modifying "you", it is modifying "can see".*

"In darkness" indicates a modification to your ability to see. Your sight works when the thing you are trying to see is in darkness. *It is not a requirement that you yourself be located in darkness.* If this were how the feature was intended, it would instead read something like:

> While you are in darkness, you can see normally."

When structured this way, the prepositional phrase "in darkness" is modifying "you". This is not how the feature is written, and so Devil's Sight allows you to see into or through darkness created by the *darkness* spell.

Comment: Such a clear grammar explanation, Thank you!